# How to use jQuery plugins with Kendo UI templates, mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How would you use a jQuery plugin with Kendo UI x-kendo-template?

I checked the documentation and there is no real concrete answers. 
We have a jQuery Barcode plugin that we want to use. 
In Kendo UI mobile, we made a model in our home.js file.  In our home.html file we call the data using the x-kendo-template and get the data using the #: mydataitem # syntax.  Now that we have that data we now need to pass that data to the jQuery Barcode plugin and generate it onto the page.

We are getting a property back called "MemId" from our Model in our home.js.  Now we need to use that "MemId" to pass that into the jQuery Barcode plugin as so we can generate the barcode then pass it back to the Kendo Template to render. Is this even possible.  Or should we put the element outside of the Kendo Template, in that case, how would we do this. I commented our help needs in the code below.

Our current code is below:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-barcode-plugin.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/home.js"></script>

<div data-role="layout" data-id="main"> 
<div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <!--Need to add back button and mail center buttons-->
        <span data-role="view-title"></span>
       <a href="#left-drawer" data-role="button" data-align="right" class="nav-button" data-rel="drawer"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</head>
```

**Home.html**

```
 <div data-role="view" data-layout="main" data-model="app.MemberInfo" data-title="Home" >
<div id="MemberCardHeader">
 <div data-template="memberTemplate" data-bind="source: MemberInfo">
    <!--Member card x-kendo-template id="memberTemplate" renders here-->
</div>
</div>
</div>

 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="memberTemplate">
  <div id="memberCard">
    <!--jQuery Plugin Barcode should render here-->
   <div id="Barcode"></div>
  </div>

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   //NEED HELP WITH THIS
  // BELOW IS THE SYNTAX FOR THE JQUERY BARCODE BUT THIS MAY NOT BE THE SPOT TO DO THIS. How would we pass the ""
   $("#Barcode").barcode("DYNAMIC-TEXT-FOR-MEMID", "code128")
 </script>
```

**Home.js**

```
var app = app || {};
 app.MemberInfo = (function (){
   var membersInfoModel = (function() { 
     var memberInfoModel = {
         MemId: {
                type: "number",
                field: 'MyMemberAccount.ConstituentId'
            }
     }
   };
   //THE REST OF OUR MODEL AND DATA IS PASSED FROM CODE. NOT POSTING HERE.

 }());

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an [init](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/view#events-init) event handler to your View that contains that template. Then your code could be called from there.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I think you would need something like...

Add an `init` handler to the view element

```
<div data-role="view"
     data-layout="main"
     data-model="app.MemberInfo"
     data-title="Home"
     data-init="app.homeView.onInit">
```

Then the `onInit` function would be:

```
var onInit = function(initEvent) {
    initEvent.view.contentElement().find("#Barcode").barcode("DYNAMIC-TEXT-FOR-MEMID", "code128");
};
```

---

Another alternative would be to create a custom Kendo widget for your Barcode that just wrappers the jQuery barcode widget. Then you could have a special `data-role` attribute that would initialize the widget, like:

```
<div id="Barcode" data-role="barcode"></div>
```

But that is a lot more work to properly set up the custom Kendo widget.